# Is there a way to replicate pwd in a volume mount for docker in a boot2docker context?

Tags: docker, provisioning, boot2docker, docker-compose

So currently I can do: `docker -v .:/usr/src/app` or even specify it in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
```

But when I attempt to define this in my `Dockerfile`:

```
VOLUME .:/usr/src/app
```

It doesn't mount anything.

Now I understand the complexities in that I'm using OSX and so I have to virtualize the environment to run Docker via boot2docker, and that boot2docker solves the copy issue by mounting `/User` to the linux machine running Docker.

The documentation wants me to be explicit, but since my explicitness would require me to name my user (in this case `/User/krainboltgreene/code/krainboltgreene/blankrails`) it seems non-idiomatic, as that obviously doesn't work on other people's environments.

What's the solution for this? I mean, I can technically get this all working without (as noted above the CLI and compose works fine), but it means not being able to do project specific provisioning (bower install, npm install, vulcanize, etc).

Comment: Note: `COPY` works just fine with `.` as a path.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a host directory for a volume inside a Dockerfile, because of the portability reasons you mention (not everyone will have the same directories and there are security issues regarding mounting sensitive files).

If you instead do:

```
VOLUME /usr/src/app
```

Docker will automatically set up a volume at run-time for the folder, which will be mapped to a directory under `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

If you want to be able to quickly make changes during development, I would suggest using `COPY` in the Dockerfile, but mounting local changes over the top with a volume at run-time. This has the disadvantage that if you volume mount a folder, all the contents of that directory in the container will be hidden (rather than merged).

Comment: "projec specific provisioning" refers to things like `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Changing it to `VOLUME /sr/src/app` didn't solve the issue sadly, as it doesn't copy over anything since I'm in the `boot2docker` environment.

Comment: so why not just do a COPY then? I don't really follow where you're going with this.

Comment: Also, nothing so far has anything to do with boot2docker, it would be the same on Linux.

Comment: Because `COPY` is not the same as `VOLUME`, it doesn't auto-update. I want to share the directory, run provisioning, and be able to use the server.

Comment: Is this just for quickly doing things during development? I have a suggestion then.

Comment: This is for development, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85199/discussion-between-krainboltgreene-and-adrian-mouat).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for that, but I hope the above helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker run -v .:/usr/src/app ...` command as well as the `docker-compose` definitions are executing during **runtime**. Whereas the `Dockerfile` instructions are executed during **build time**.

By the way the instruction in your `Dockerfile` is syntactically incorrect. It should be `VOLUME /usr/src/app` instead.

That `VOLUME` keyword only defines that later during runtime this location will be stored on a volume. So all files that you add by further `Dockerfile` instructions or manual *commits* to that location are ignored and not added to the resulting image.

Now during *runtime* when you did not specify a volume it Docker will generate a volume for you which is empty by default.

To have your `docker-compose` setup working for other colleagues you could simply make the `docker-compose` configuration file being part of your `blankrails` project folder. Everybody then runs `docker-compose` from within that directory and your provided configuration will work.

**EDIT**:

I do not know exactly what you mean with project specific provisioning. But if your aim is to provide default contents for the defined volume you could do something like the following:

- Add all required project files during the `Dockerfile` build to a `/bootstrap` folder on the image.
- Instead of executing your app directly use a start shell script for `CMD`.
- In that start script you can check whether the volume mounted to `/usr/src/app` is empty or not. When it is empty copy all the `/bootstrap` contents into it.
- Afterwards start your app from within that script in foreground.

With that approach you can easily provide a default file set for mounted volumes. And when you re-use that volume e.g. after a container restart the container just works with the files that are on the volume without touching them again during startup. So modified files will be persisted.

Comment: > Whereas the Dockerfile instructions are executed during build time.

Okay, I see where you're going, but `COPY` works just fine!

Comment: A made an edit to my answer and added some thoughts about project provisioning.

Comment: I'm a bit hazy, but this seems to have the same issue as `COPY` vs `VOLUME`, in that `COPY` doesn't "sync" files?